# Quantum Locking and gravity

Tags: electromagnetism, superconductivity

Can a device be constructed of a super conducting disk connected to a electromagnet that generates a field such that the disc locks "in" the field generated by the electromagnet such that the device self levitates without the need for track or permanent magnets?

Answer (score 2):

No, the locking occurs relative to the field which is now moving with the device.  It's like trying to push your dashboard to move your car.